# Using cp_analytics plugin for Expression Engine2

Tags: ee2, google-analytics

In a website I am busy building in EE2, I need to build a metric dashboard displaying all sorts of tracked analytics for the website. I installed the cp_analytics plugin into Expression Engine I bought from devot:ee which looks amazing, but how would I retrieve and display other google analytics values such as viewing by device type, visitor stats etc? I suppose I probably need to link the site to a Analytics account? But is there some sort of API I can use to retrieve these values and display them on the dashboard?

Also, is there built in analytics in EE for EE specifc analysis i.e. page views, email analytics etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two good alternatives to CP Analytics:

- [Republic Analytics](http://republiclabs.com/expressionengine/republic-analytics) shows a lot of information;
- [Entry Analytics](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-analytics) show info close to the entry on CP;

Maybe, one of them shows what you need.